# Azure Face API - someone can use another person's photo for Identification

Tags: azure, security, azure-cognitive-services, identification, face-api

I am developing a system to identify persons, I am using an app (to take photos) and then send the photo to a Web Asp.Net Core API (It use Microsoft Azure Face API). But the system is not secure!. Because someone using a Photo of other people can validate to another person !. The system is for validate a person! If someone use a photo then the system is not secure!
Some idea about What can I do to check that the person is a person and not is a photo of a another person?

Comment: The technology/method used as such is not secure enough for authentication.  similarly to fingerprints it can be easily copies without additional measures.  In my oppinion this is also the reason why it isn't used a lot and surely not for critical services.   you could use it together with an alternative like 2FA or something, but if user experience was the aim then there's not much use.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly agreed with @jcuypers's said. Based on my understanding for Azure Face API, I think it's just a general algorithm collection to classify person faces from images. Meanwhile, according to the reference of REST API [`Face - Identify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/face/face/identify), it will reply many different identifications with high probability value from one same image, so it can not be used in secure field like identification authentication. At least for secure-less scenario, you need to enable stronger authentication mechanism as second solution to deal with face identify conflict for an image when Azure Face API return more than one possible results.

Recommended that to use a professional industrial solution, or you can use the existing real face images as much as possible to train a model for face identify using industrial deep-learning framework like Tensorflow to make it enough reliable by yourself and use the model in your app via TensorFlow Lite.